Is environment model necessary for higher-order procedures?
When learning SICP, 6.001 lec15 has:

A good understanding of the environment model tells me why (IMHO) C++ will never have a fully-functional map, filter, and fold-right/fold-left procedures that are as convenient as Scheme’s

SICP implements map, filter, fold-left (IMHO they are all based on recursion or iteration):
(define (map proc items)
  (if (null? items)
      nil
      (cons (proc (car items))
            (map proc (cdr items)))))

(define (filter predicate sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        ((predicate (car sequence))
         (cons (car sequence)
               (filter predicate (cdr sequence))))
        (else (filter predicate (cdr sequence)))))

(define (fold-left op initial sequence)
  (define (iter result rest)
    (if (null? rest)
        result
        (iter (op result (car rest))
              (cdr rest))))
  (iter initial sequence))

Here each recursive calls map will create one new env for each argument list (proc items), so they can be independent (similar for proc and cons etc).
But in my opinion, in C++ the above code can be done with the same ideas based on stack. So independence is still held.
Why does the lec say "C++ will never have a fully-functional map" due to "environment model"?

Based on this comment, in C++ map and filter can be  implemented with for loop. proc etc func can be passed with one func pointer. For fold-left, we can use namespace to create one local iter although maybe not elegant. Then how to answer "the relationship between environment model and lackness of map in pre-C++11" (this is one more clear rephrase of the above question based on the comments below)?

To be fair, that document was written well before the C++11 standard, which added quite a lot of functionality needed to emulate a map function like the one shown.

Have you seen how OLD that information is? Higher order functions are easy to build from functions that accept lambda expressions/functions and return new lambda functions. Then there are the algorithms like std::ranges::fold_right now. It is also not impossible to write monadic style (member) functions (e.g see std::optional monadic operations), So I think C++ has come a long way and you could emulate it pretty well by now.

@PepijnKramer Thanks. I am one freshman and I will dig into this problem when learning c++ specifically. Currently I am learning SICP as the preparation for CRLS.

Also there is a reason there are different programming languages, they all have their strengths and weaknesses. And sometimes concepts just don't carry over that well (if at all). So my advice when you pickup C++, just start from scratch and accept you will not be able to make any meaningful translation from what you are used to now to C++.  C++ has its own philosophy, centered around around scopes and object lifetimes (destructors)

Your link to the lecture doesn't work for me, I get "Forbidden".

@Barmar Do you mean https://people.csail.mit.edu/dalleyg/6.001/SP2007/recitation15.pdf? IMHO mit domain shouldn't be forbidden, even for GFW. If so, https://web.archive.org/web/20240713202610/https://people.csail.mit.edu/dalleyg/6.001/SP2007/recitation15.pdf should work.

@PepijnKramer Reply to your modified 1st comment: "monadic style (member) functions" is a bit beyond my understanding ability implied by my 1st comment. I don't understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Overview M a and M b meanings. I will return to this when learning c++.

Note, since C++23 you can write the factorial function referred to by the links in @An5Drama remarks as : auto factorial = [](this auto self, int i) {  return (i == 1) ? 1 : i * self(i - 1); };.  Which is the notation for a recursive lambda expression in C++.

The link works now, maybe it was a temporary server problem.

I don't know what the author meant there, but my understanding is that the most pertinent issue here is having map use an anonymous function which has access and modifies some variables external to it which are internal to the function which makes the map call:
(define (foo x y)
  (define (bar z)
    (set! x z)
    y)
  (map bar (list 1 2 3)))


Thanks. This special example shows why env model matters.

Isn't this what I wrote in the comments? the environment model has to do with the fact that when you define a function in scheme, you can use in its body not just the parameters of the function, but also the variables that are in the scope where you define the function, and what happens is that the function will have access those values even if you use it out of that scope where it was defined. But that's something that is easily accomplished with lambdas and, before C++11, with structs with the call operator. Take auto foo = [](auto i){ return [i]{ work(i); }(Foo{}); foo(); will work.

@Enlico I don't know. I don't know whether lambdas in C++11 have persistent lexical scope. then, your "structs with call operator" is extremely terse bordering on being opaque to someone not already familiar with the technique. and I only skimmed through the comments, and the answer too, to be honest. I saw a mention of laziness, didn't understand the relevance and stopped reading. mostly I wanted to stress the point about mutatable bindings. without mutation it is much easier to emulate the closures by various techniques, like inlining the values inside the lambda function itself.

@WillNess, but +1 to your answer, ahah, let's be clear. It's just that the question half referred to C++'s supposed inability to emulate that code, so I addrresed that within the first 4 lines of my answer.

As others have said, that link is very old. Things have changed a lot since then.
The short answer, in my opinion, is that the map you describe, exists already in C++ (C++20), and it's called std::ranges::views::transform, which
can be used like this
auto w = v | transform(f);

which "corresponds" to
(define w (map f v))

in Scheme.
I've quoted corresponds because I don't know exactly how things happen at run-time for the Scheme code above. I know that std::ranges::views::transform is lazy, i.e. no work is actually performed (in the sense of f is not invoked at all) when writing the C++ line above. Only when accessing the values of w via the range API, will those values be actually computed, hence f will be called.
But I know it works, in terms of lazyness, like the corresponding Haskell code (which resembles the Scheme code a lot):
let w = map f v

Furthemore, the concept of "mapping" is not even as narrow as the one implied by the snippet of code and the claim that

C++ will never have a fully-functional map

because that map is an ad-hoc implementation of map for lists. So it's as "functional" as a program that explicitly deals with lists all along without ever defining high-level abstractions.
... Which is ok in Scheme because everything is a list, true, but you'd still have to redefine map_assocmap to run a function on the values of an "associative map" (which would still be a list, at the end of the day, in Scheme, e.g. (define myassocmap '((k1 v1) (k2 v2) (k3 v3))), but map_assocmap would not be map, because (map_assocmap f myassocmap) would have to call the f only on v1, v2, v3.)
But the point is that the concept of mapping is more general, and it pertains to Functors, as known in category-theory and functional-programming.
And C++ does offer something in that direction. For instance, you can map an optional, in C++: given a std::optional<T> and a function of type U(T), it makes sense to execute that function on the value inside the optional, if there is one, thus obtaining a non-empty optional of type std::optional<U>, or to return an empty std::optional<U> (std::nullopt) if the original optional was empty. This, in C++, is the member function std::optional<T>::transform.
This would correspond to the following, in Scheme
(define (mapOpt f opt)
  (if (nullOpt? opt)
      'nullOpt
      (f (makeOpt (unwrapOpt opt)))))

assuming that one has defined the nullOpt?+'nullOpt+makeOpt+unwrapOpt API.

I don't know much about c++ but just know some C++ syntax shared by C (I only learnt C in one university introduction course before). 1. Does | in v | transform(f) mean logical or? But that seems to be nonsense. Here | is more like pipe in shell. 2. "So it's as "functional" as a program that explicitly deals with lists all along without ever defining high-level abstractions." IMHO this means we can actually use for loop in C to  achieve that, is that right? 3. Do you mean map_assocmap can be achieved also by transform which can't be done by Scheme map?


Functor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_(functional_programming) is more complex. IMHO it can be implemented as one generic procedure which I have learnt in SICP section 2.4 and SDF Software Design for Flexibility chapter 3.


Regarding the first comment: 1. v | transform(f) === transform(v, f), so yes, like shell's pipe syntax, via operator|-overloading; 2. I'm not sure what you mean; 3. No, std::ranges::views::transform is not particularly more general than map: map deals with lists only, transform operates on ranges in general, which means anything that can be traversed via begin/++/!=end, which includes non-sequential things as well, like trees, but neither of them can be used on an entity representing an optional (a so called Maybe in functional programming).

Plus I've been intentially hand-wavy, as the 2 languages are very different. I guess in Scheme you'd expect that (map_assocmap f myassocmap) gives back to you something with the same API of myassocmap, even if its elements are computed lazily, whereas views::transform in C++ will give you back just a range (which means you can't operate on it with the API of myassocmap, because that object as an entirely different type), and you'd have to eagerly process that ranges and convert it back to the type of myassocmap, if you needed that type.

I should stress that the whole point of my answer is 2 folds: 1. C++ can do that thing in your snippet perfectly as of now; 2. that thing in your snippet is still not this very general convenient thing that writer of post claimed, because it only operates on lists. The rest of my answer is just meant to serve as point from which you can go and look up other stuff on the web or in books to learn new things.


Clarification to my 2nd comment: for (i = 0; i < length(items); i++) {items[i]=proc(items[i])}. 2. Summary of your reply to my 3rd comment: so c++ namespace implies transform won't be general/generic and return type is also restricted implicitly by namespace. 3. One small question: do you know why lecturer says "environment model" influence map implementation in c++ before c++11 (sorry for not saying this explicitly in post since I don't know different standards of c++ may have big differences. Maybe this should be one new follow-up question)?



Yeah, but that's the impl of an eager transform, not lazy. Look up the lazyness concept in Haskell. 2. The namespace is not the point here (despite defining a fully generic transform under std::ranges:: would be very confusing). The point is just that std::ranges::views::transform is the functional map "just" for one funtctor, i.e. the list functor (which is not std::list in C++, but a generic range); there's other functors out there, and some are offered by the STL, e.g. std::optional.


But Scheme's map is not more general, as it too only works on the list functor. The point is that in Scheme everything is a list, so unless you start buliting your own abstractions (e.g. the maybe-API I assumed at the bottom of my answer), Scheme doesn't give you any other functors out of the box than the list. Actually there's another incarnation of list functor which doesn't support map: the string! Yeah, that's an example: Scheme's map can't be used to upper-case a string, for instance.


I think it's just referring to closures. With lambdas (or even just struct+operator(), so before C++11) you do have closures in C++ as well. 2007 was long ago. Maybe the point is that in pre-C++11 you would necessarily have to go through the hassle of defining a struct+operator(), which is obviously not at all convenient as writing a lambda.


Let us continue this discussion in chat.
